# Weights in Markowitz portfolio[Matlab]

Tags: matlab

Hello everyone I read article about Plotting an Efficient Frontier Using portopt. https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/plotting-an-efficient-frontier-using-portopt.html?fbclid=IwAR1VOzBOHWsEXxBi0Y_MkWkQyuqbef0RHripNiolO8GtlkSD2MHZ5ikZnYA#responsive_offcanvas I would like to know how to get concrete weights for concrete xy coordinates from Efficient Frontier. If anyone knows how to do it, please answer.

Comment: Are you expecting a theoretical formula for the weights, or an implementation?

Comment: Implementation.